# FullCalendar - only load events between dates

Tags: php, jquery, sql, fullcalendar

sorry for my english! 
I'm using FullCalendar with sql and php.
The thing is that I have a lot of events in the db (more than 4000) and I would like to load only the actual week events and on click to next/prev button load again the events for this week...

My .js is:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView:'agendaWeek',
    events: base+"v.php?acction=start",
    .....
```

And my query in v.php is:

```
$query_visitas ='SELECT *,concat_ws(" ",name,surname) as title, 
visit_id as id, concat_ws(" ",date_start,time_start) as start,
concat_ws(" ",date_end,time_end) as end FROM visits v 
LEFT JOIN pacient p ON v.pacient_id = p.id 
ORDER BY START';
```

Thanks for the suggestions, because I'm going crazy!

Comment: My I suggest that you provide links to FullCalendar for reference.   Also, please clarify what issues you are having with your code and what the expected result is that you are looking for.   Are you seeing results in the calendar from your query and need help with your SQL or are you haveing issues rendering dates all together?

Comment: Sorry but the site is an intranet so I can not give a link... I have troubles with the SQL and passing the variables... thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fetch FullCalendar events from the server using JSON the `start` and `end` dates of the displayed calendar as sent with the request. See *[events as a JSON feed](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/)* for documentation.

You will need to consume these values and use them to filter the results that are returned by your `SELECT`. It gets a bit tricky because we need to find rows that:

- Have a end time after `start` and before `end`.
- Have a start time after `start` and before `end`.
- Have a start time before `start` and and end time after `end`.

You will need to use `CONCAT_WS()` to form a valid start and end datetime string, and then convert it to a proper `DATE` datatype using `STR_TO_DATE()`.

```
// FullCalendar V1 sends timestamps
$start =  isset($_REQUEST['start'])? intval($_REQUEST['start']) : 0;
$end =  isset($_REQUEST['end'])? intval($_REQUEST['end']) : 0;

// FullCalendar V2 sends ISO8601 date strings
$start =  isset($_REQUEST['start'])? strtotime($_REQUEST['start']) : 0;
$end =  isset($_REQUEST['end'])? strtotime($_REQUEST['end']) : 0;

// convert the timestamps to date strings for the SQL
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', $start);
$end_date = date('Y-m-d', $end);

// ordinarily you would use a prepared statement, but since you didn't specify a driver they variables are included inline - should be sanitized by date()`
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *, 
        visit_id as id, 
        CONCAT_WS(' ', name, surname) as title, 
        CONCAT_WS(' ', date_start, time_start) as start,
        CONCAT_WS(' ', date_end, time_end) as end 
    FROM visits v 
    LEFT JOIN pacient p 
        ON v.pacient_id = p.id 
    WHERE
        -- anything with an end between the start/end
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(' ', date_end, time_end), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') BETWEEN '{$start_date}' AND '{$end_date}'
        OR 
        -- anything with an end between the start/end
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(' ', date_start, time_start), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') BETWEEN '{$start_date}' AND '{$end_date}'
        OR 
        -- anything with a start before the start and an end after the end
        (
            STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(' ', date_start, time_start), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') < '{$start_date}' 
            AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(' ', date_end, time_end), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') > '{$end_date}'
        )
    ORDER BY start, end
SQL;
```

Comment: UAU! we are really close! but now is only is showing events until noon, It shows no event later... Thank you very much for the approach, can you help me to finish it?

Comment: You might want to double check the timezones.

Comment: Uops... and where or how I have to check this? Thank you!

Comment: The date/time/timezone on your computer as well as the server. If you can output the sql query to the error log it should help to debug as well.

Comment: So sorry but I don't know how to do it :( I'm not an expert :(

Comment: If it helps I attach an image of the result of this query... ![Image of the calendar](http://postimg.org/image/6szxp2o5x/)

Comment: I can't really tell, but my guess would be that `strtotime($_REQUEST['start'])` is getting a date in your timezone and then converting it to a timestamp in the server's timezone, then using that to filter values from the database in your timezone. Time is really tricky.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93914/discussion-between-curosio-and-doublesharp).

Comment: I get the solution! changing: '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s' to '%Y-%m-%d' works like charm! thanks a lot doublesharp!!!